# How to stop d3.drag triggering mouseover/mouseout events in chrome

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following d3 visualisation. The darker colour at the top indicates that a node has been selected. When I mouseover a non selected node it changes opacity so a user can see which node would be selected if I click.

This is achieved via a CSS style sheet and the following js/d3:

```
nodeSelection.select("circle").on('mouseover', function(e) {
             d3.select(this).classed("hover", true);
            _this.fireDataEvent("mouseOverNode", this);
        });

        nodeSelection.select("circle").on('mouseout', function(e) {
            d3.select(this).classed("hover", false);
            _this.fireDataEvent("mouseOutNode", this);
        });
```

So, far, so good. However, when I drag, the drag function seems to randomly trigger mouse over and mouse out events on the nodes that I am not dragging. This causes the node opacity to flicker. If I watch on the development tools in chrome I can see that this is because it is causing nodes to gain the class "hover". The code above to add this CSS class appears nowhere else, and by use of the console logging, I have confirmed that mouseover and mouseout events are being fired. These nodes are often far from the cursor.

This issue does not occur in Firefox.

[image: My Graph]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE: I actually managed to fix this almost immediately after posting this. I just explicitly de-register the listeners inside drag start, and re register in drag end. It might still be interesting to some people if they are having similar issues.

My drag function now looks like:

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
            .on("dragstart", function(d) {
                console.log("dragstart");
                d.dragstart = d3.mouse(this); // store this
                d.fixedbeforedrag = d.fixed;
                d.fixed=true;

                // deregister listeners
                nodeSelection.select("circle").on("mouseover", null).on("mouseout", null); 
            })
            .on("drag", function(d) {
                d.px = d.x; // previous x
                d.py = d.y;
                var m = d3.mouse(this);
                d.x += m[0] - d.dragstart[0];
                d.y += m[1] - d.dragstart[1];
                nodeSelection.attr("transform", "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")");
                _this.getForce().start();
            })
            .on("dragend", function(d) {
                console.log("dragend");
                delete d.dragstart;
                d.fixed = d.fixedbeforedrag;
                //reregisters listeners
                _this.updateSVG(); 
            });
```

Comment: I am not sure if that is the right approach. I searched for the same topic and came along the if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return; and d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation(); expressions, but I am still not sure how to place them right to prevent the mouseover while dragging.

Comment: d3.event.defaultPrevented will prevent default browser behaviour. Stop propagation prevents the event being sent up the DOM heirarchy. Neither of those will prevent explicit listeners on the same object being called. The root cause of this is/was a bug in chrome that meant it did not keep the locations of the svg element and the mouse pointer well enough integrated, so it was firing mouseout just because it hadn't updated the element position fast enough. Then mouseover when it caught up. These kind of issue are constantly getting fixed/reoccuring.

Comment: jQuery exhibits a similar problem with dragging interaction with mouseover. I'd suspect it is due to the Chrome bugs you cite. Removing mouseover event handlers (with .off()) seems to be the only solution. Thanks for posting this as it solved my problem. Different software same manifestation.

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful. My guess is that its because chrome executes JavaScript in multiple threads, so it can have asynchronous updating of the mouse pointer vs the svg elements.